# Asymptotic Mean of Tn

Tags: convergence-divergence, asymptotics, central-limit-theorem

So suppose that:

$$
\sqrt n(Tn - \theta) \rightarrow d\rightarrow  T \sim {N}(0,\varepsilon) 
$$

and Tn is asymptotically normal.

How do I find the asymptotical mean of Tn?

So far I have:

$$
(Tn - \theta) \approx \frac{Tn}{\sqrt n}
$$

$$
Tn \approx \frac{Tn}{\sqrt n} + \theta
$$

What's the next step? I know the answer is $\theta$, but I don't know why or how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n\rightarrow \infty$, what happens to $T_n$?

Comment: Alright, I see it, so as n approaches infinity, we are only left with theta. Got it